# Basics of Nuclear reaction

Tags: momentum, energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws

In the nuclear physics book by Krane, I was reading about how mathematically and numerically Q value of the reaction are measured. So he decided to prove it by solving it in Lab frame, And he goes saying this,

"Let's apply them (the formulas he wrote to measure Q value) first to the laboratory reference frame, in which the target nuclei are considered to be at rest (room-temperature thermal energies are negligible on the MeV scale of nuclear reactions). If we define a reaction plane by the direction of the incident beam and one of the outgoing particles, then
conserving the component of momentum perpendicular to that plane shows
immediately that the motion of the second outgoing particle must lie in the plane
as well."

1. So my first doubt is, what is a reaction plane, and why the nuclear reaction always occur in a plane only. I read some more stuffs online but was unable to understand this reason as why nuclear reaction occur in a plane.
2. Why is so that the momentum perpendicular to plane is to be conserved and is of interest?

Answer (score 2):

The diagram relating to your question about a two resultant particles interaction is as follows with me adding some axes.

[image]

Particles $a$ and $b$ are in the xy plane.
The incoming particle $a$ has momentum in the $x$ direction.
With no external forces acting the total momentum of particles $b$ and $Y$ must also be in the x direction.
As there was no initial momentum in the z direction there can be no final momentum in the z direction.
Particle $b$ has no momentum in the z direction (as it is travelling in the xy plane) thus particle $Y$ can have no momentum in the z direction.